# Convert HTML with CSS3 to PDF in Java

Tags: html, spring-boot, pdf, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am generating invoices dynamically using thymeleaf and HTML and have used bootstrap 5 to lay out the whole thing which uses CSS3 but when I need to generate a PDF from HTML, everything works fine but the layout gets messed up as the used library doesn't support CSS3.
I have tried using **flying saucer**, and **openhtmltopdf-pdfbox** but none of them gives the desired results.

**Generated HTML From thymeleaf**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                   initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style media="all">
        :root {
            --primary-color: #E01B33;
        }

        .theme-background-color {
            background-color: var(--primary-color);
        }

        .theme-text-color {
            color: var(--primary-color);
        }

        tfoot {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
   
</head>
<body>
<div class="px-4" id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2 class="fw-bold">ABC</h2>
            <br/>
            <h3>asdasdsad</h3>
            <br/>
            <text>Phone Number:- asdasdasd</text>
            <br/>
            <text>Email:- sadasdasd</text>
            <br/>
            <text>Gst No.:- asdasdasdas</text>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="text-center mt-4 fw-bold theme-text-color">Sale Invoice</h1>
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col">
            <text class="fw-bold">Bill to:</text>
            <br/>
            <text class="fw-bold">asdasdasd</text>
            <br/>
            <text>asdasdasda</text>
            <br/>
            <text>Customer Number:- asdsadasd</text>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-end">
            <text class="fw-bold">Invoice No:- 1</text>
            <br/>
            <text class="fw-bold">Invoice Date:- 20/7/2022</text>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover mt-4">
            <tr class="theme-background-color">
                <th>#</th>
                <th>HSN</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price/Unit</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
                <th>GST</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>₹ 100</td>
                <td>₹ 100(10)</td>
                <td class="text-wrap">₹ 45(GST%5)</td>
                <td>₹ 945</td>
            </tr>
            <tfoot class="border-bottom border-dark ">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="fw-bold">Total</td>
                <td colspan="3" class="fw-bold">10</td>
                <td class="fw-bold">45</td>
                <td class="fw-bold">945</td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td class="fw-bold text-muted">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="fw-bold text-muted">Hello terms</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub Total</td>
                    <td>₹ 1,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="theme-background-color">
                    <td class="fw-bold">Total</td>
                    <td class="fw-bold">₹ 945</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Received</td>
                    <td>₹ 400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Balance</td>
                    <td>₹ 545</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Java Code to generate PDF**

```java
    public void generatePDF(FileOutputStream outputStream, String html) throws IOException {
        PdfRendererBuilder pdfBuilder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
        pdfBuilder.useFastMode();
        pdfBuilder.withUri("path/to/pdf.file");
        pdfBuilder.toStream(outputStream);
        pdfBuilder.run();
//        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
//        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
//        renderer.layout();
//        renderer.createPDF(outputStream, false);
//        renderer.finishPDF();
    }
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openhtmltopdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openhtmltopdf-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openhtmltopdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openhtmltopdf-pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openhtmltopdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openhtmltopdf-java2d</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Any of these things didn't work out, but I was using JavaFX, so I used its WebView to show previews and used its print API to generate PDFs.